# Creating an array from textbox/listbox

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, listbox

I classify myself as a beginner in programing. I have a userform that first looks up a number presented by the user. Example 12345, 12346,12347. The number entered into the textbox is searched for and then added to the listbox as a valid number.  After the user enters all the numbers needed, they should be able to click change and update the records accordingly.

```
Private Sub Change_Click()
Dim i As Long

For i = LBound(RunArray) To UBound(RunArray)
    ' Code to update each record, still working on it.
Next

End Sub

Private Sub RunNumber_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger,     ByVal Shift As Integer)
Dim RunArray() As String
Dim RunCount As Integer
RunCount = 0

If KeyCode = 13 Then
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
        Set RunFind = .Find(What:=RunNumber, _
                     After:=.Cells(.Cells.count), _
                     LookIn:=xlValues, _
                     LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                     SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                     MatchCase:=False)
        If Not RunFind Is Nothing Then
            ReDim Preserve RunArray(RunCount)
            RunArray(RunCount) = RunNumber.Value
            RunNumberList.AddItem RunNumber.Value
            RunNumber.Value = ""
            RunCount = RunCount + 1
        Else
            MsgBox "The Run Number you entered was not found, Please the number and try again."
            RunNumber.Value = ""
        End If
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub CreateArrayFromListbox()
  Dim nIndex As Integer
  Dim vArray() As Variant

  ' dimension the array first instead of using 'preserve' in the loop
  ReDim vArray(ListBox1.ListCount - 1)
  
  For nIndex = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    vArray(nIndex) = ListBox1.List(nIndex)
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: first off, thank you for your help.  as for the code i'm not entirely sure this need to either be combined or integrated into my existing code. would this actually be in with my change_click() or as an independent? again thank you for your help.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do... you can remove the 1st line and the last line, and put the remaining code in your change_click(), replacing what you have.. but it not really going to do anything until you add your own code after it to do whatever it is you are planning to do with the array. You will also need to change ListBox1 to the name of whatever you named your listbox.

Comment: If you provide some comments in your answer that'd be better.

Comment: i'm pretty much sure you can do this without looping. `Arr=Me.listbox1.list`, something like that.If it doesn't work, check the dimensions of the array. Probably `Arr` needs to be a dynamic variant Array..

Answer (score 0):

i have an example how to do it with a combobox, (it's the same with a listbox, just change the name accordingly.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i&
Dim Arr()
With Me.ComboBox1
    For i = 1 To 1000
        .AddItem "Item " & i
    Next i

    Arr = .List

    .Clear
End With

For i = 0 To 999
    Debug.Print Arr(i, 0)
Next i

Erase Arr
End Sub
```

this is just a sample code, in real coding, you won't clear the combobox this early, or erase the array.

The results are shown in the immediate window  (alt-F11 , and Ctrl-g).

Note : the array is 2 dimendionned, and 0 based (`Option base 1`, after `Option Explicit`can make the whole module 1-based (arrays start at 1) ).