# VBA: Userform Listbox to String

Tags: vba, listbox, userform

I have a Userform where people loop through and add on each click an item to a listbox. By clicking another buttom the items should be converted to a string with a comma as delimiter.

```
lstDatabase.AddItem txtfruit.Value
```

I tried to convert the listbox to an array and then to a string but this seems not to work

```
Dim deliverynoteArray() As Variant
Dim deliverynote_list As String

deliverynoteArray = lstDatabase.List
deliverynote_list = Join(deliverynoteArray, ",")
```

The "add" and the "convert" are both in Private Sub _click sections. Might that be the problem? That the data is not accessible?

Comment: "seems not to work" - always useful to explain what it does *instead* of work.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44457705/478884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When use `deliverynoteArray = lstDatabase.List` the code will create a 2D array, and `Join` works only on 1D arrays. So, after placing the list box element in the array you should use `Transpose`, which transforms a 2D array **having multiple rows** and one column, in a 1D type.

Try replacing `deliverynote_list = Join(deliverynoteArray, ",")` with:

```
   deliverynote_list = Join(Application.Transpose(deliverynoteArray), ",")
   Debug.Print deliverynote_list 'just to see it in Immediate Window...
```